# Get current day in drop-down list

Tags: jquery

So I have my HTML drop-down list

```
<select name="Todays_Day">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way for JQuery to select today's day? so for example today is 6/12/2014 so it would auto select Thursday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an array with the days of the week and then using [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)(returns the day of the week (0-6) for the specified date according to local time.) from Date object get the current day. Then you can use it to pass to jquery val method:

```js
var d =["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][(new Date()).getDay()]
$("select").val(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Todays_Day">
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you add explanation what you did

Comment: cannot get any shorter and simpler than this!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var td = new Date().getDay();
    td = (td == 0) ? 7 : td;
    $('select[name=Todays_Day]').find('option').eq( td ).prop('selected', true)
    .end().change();
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Eux3R/)